# react-native-webview getItem() from localStorage

Tags: reactjs, react-native

in my react-native app I use a webview via react-native-webview. In this, I need to get an item from the localStorage. I tried it with injectedJavaScript={myInjectedJs}, but I don't get anything back.

What am I doing wrong?

**Tab.tsx**

```
export default function TabEnergy({navigation} : {navigation: any}) {

  return <WebView 
  source={{ uri: DevUrls.BASE_URL_DEV }} 
  javaScriptEnabled={true}
  domStorageEnabled={true}
  injectedJavaScript={myInjectedJs}
  />;
}

let myInjectedJs = `(function(){
  ${`console.log('**', window.localStorage.getItem('authenticationObject')) `}
})();`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `onMessage={e => console.log(e.nativeEvent.data))` prop to `WebView` component.
And post that info back into ReactNative by calling `window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage()`

```
export default function TabEnergy({navigation} : {navigation: any}) {
  const webviewRef = useRef();

  const onSomeEvent = () => {
    webviewRef.current.injectJavaScript(
      `(function(){
         window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(window.localStorage.getItem('authenticationObject'))
      })();`
    )
  }


  return (
    <WebView 
      ref={webviewRef}
      source={{ uri: DevUrls.BASE_URL_DEV }} 
      javaScriptEnabled={true}
      domStorageEnabled={true}
      injectedJavaScript={myInjectedJs}
      onMessage={e => console.log(e.nativeEvent.data))
    />
  );
}

let myInjectedJs = `(function(){
  window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(window.localStorage.getItem('authenticationObject'))
})();`
```

Comment: Thank you, that works fine! I have another question: How can I trigger this event when I leave the screen? In my case the app has a bottom navigation bar. Every time I leave a tab (that loads a webview) I want to store the value inside the AsyncStorage. Any idea?

Comment: You should add a ref for WebView and use another method that is offered by WebView.
Remove `injectedJavaScript` and use `webviewRef.current.injectJavascript(`your code`)`.
All of this should be bound to blur event of navigation

Comment: Do you have an example for what you mean? I'm new to react and react-native.

Comment: I've updated original answer. You can trigger onSomeEvent to execute some js in webview.

Comment: Thank you for you effort! I added the code, but there is an error with webViewRef.current: Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)

Comment: `webViewRef.current?.injectJavaScript`

Comment: Unfortunately, this has no effect ^^. Still undefined.

Comment: Haha I found it: I missed this. :D

Comment: Do you have an idea, how I can receive two items from localStorage in one call?